# removing element from parent node with loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

today i've got this struggle to solve, so i have a array of html elements (e.g 3 inputs)
and i want to delete every single one from the dom. so i must iterate loop over them but i also should not increment the value because it will skip every other elements and that means i must only delete first element of array until it exists, so for this task i use this code

```
 while(inputs[0]) {
    inputs[0].parentNode.removeChild(inputs[0]);
 }
```

and this works perfectly and removes all elements.
but what about `for...of` loop? it also gets every value of array and what if i just delete first input every time it's getting  a element from array ? like this:

```
for(input of inputs){
    inputs[0].parentNode.removeChild(inputs[0]);
}
```

i also tried this and in the 3 inputs it left third one (did not delete it)
so i want to know why? can someone show me how it missed third one? (graphical explanation will be the best)

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the first iteration, the iterator is at position zero, there are three elements. You delete one.

```
 v
 0 1 2
```

At the second iteration, the iterator is at position one, there are two elements. You delete one.

```
   v
 0 1
```

At the third iteration, the iteration stops, as there is only one element, and the index is at three, so it is outside of the array. No delete operation is done.

```
      v
 0
```

The main problem/advantage here is that `nodes` is a *live collection*. If it would not be live (e.g. if you use `querySelectorAll`), then the second version would work:

```
 //     v declare variables!
 for(const input of document.querySelectorAll("input"))
   input.remove(); // < remove is way easier
```

Comment: yes but in your answer there are first element ([0]) is removed then the third one (`[1]`) (because there are only second and third one left) so that means second element must be left in array but in my code there is third left why?

Comment: No, you always remove the first one. if you would remove `input` instead of `inputs[0]`, then the second would be left